# How do you plot bar charts in gnuplot?

Tags: graph, charts, plot, gnuplot, bar-chart

How do you plot bar charts in gnuplot with text labels?

Answer (score 139):

Simple bar graph:

[image: bar graph]

```
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
plot "data.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
```

data.dat:

```
0 label       100
1 label2      450
2 "bar label" 75
```

**If you want to style your bars differently, you can do something like:**

[image: multi color bar graph]

```
set style line 1 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lc rgb "blue"

set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.5

plot "data.dat" every ::0::0 using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes ls 1, \
     "data.dat" every ::1::2 using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes ls 2
```

**If you want to do multiple bars for each entry:**

data.dat:

```
0     5
0.5   6


1.5   3
2     7


3     8
3.5   1
```

gnuplot:

```
set xtics ("label" 0.25, "label2" 1.75, "bar label" 3.25,)

set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid

plot 'data.dat' every 2    using 1:2 with boxes ls 1,\
     'data.dat' every 2::1 using 1:2 with boxes ls 2
```

[image: barchart_multi]

**If you want to be tricky and use some neat gnuplot tricks:**

Gnuplot has psuedo-columns that can be used as the index to color:

```
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:0 with boxes lc variable
```

[image: barchart_multi2]

Further you can use a function to pick the colors you want:

```
mycolor(x) = ((x*11244898) + 2851770)
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:(mycolor($0)) with boxes lc rgb variable
```

[image: barchart_multi3]

Note: you will have to add a couple other basic commands to get the same effect as the sample images.

Comment: For many applications it's more convenient to use the `histogram` plotting style, especially for grouping and stacking values.

Comment: @Christoph Hi,If I want to add key for this type of graph? what should I do ? For example If I want to add a key which say the blue line is "winter" and the red line is "summer"

Comment: @alex Not sure, which of all those examples you mean: with `lc rgb variable` you cannot have different key entries.

Comment: For whatever reason, I had to use the directive 'notitle' after the each plot clause in order to surpress the legend from coming up.

Answer (score 25):

```
plot "data.dat" using 2: xtic(1) with histogram
```

Here data.dat contains data of the form

```
title 1
title2 3
"long title" 5
```

Answer (score 20):

I would just like to expand upon the top answer, which uses GNUPlot to create a bar graph, for absolute beginners because I read the answer and was still confused from the deluge of syntax.

We begin by writing a text file of GNUplot commands. Lets call it commands.txt:

```
set term png
set output "graph.png"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
plot "data.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
```

`set term png` will set GNUplot to output a .png file and `set output "graph.png"` is the name of the file it will output to.

The next two lines are rather self explanatory. The fifth line contains a lot of syntax.

```
plot "data.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
```

`"data.dat"` is the data file we are operating on. `1:3` indicates we will be using column 1 of data.dat for the x-coordinates and column 3 of data.dat for the y-coordinates. `xtic()` is a function that is responsible for numbering/labeling the x-axis. `xtic(2)`, therefore, indicates that we will be using column 2 of data.dat for labels.

"data.dat" looks like this:

```
0 label       100
1 label2      450
2 "bar label" 75
```

To plot the graph, enter `gnuplot commands.txt` in terminal.

Answer (score 13):

I recommend Derek Bruening's bar graph generator Perl script. Available at http://www.burningcutlery.com/derek/bargraph/

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use the style histograms provide by gnuplot. This is an example if you have two file in output:

```
set style data histograms
 set style fill solid
 set boxwidth 0.5
 plot "file1.dat" using 5 title "Total1" lt rgb "#406090",\
      "file2.dat" using 5 title "Total2" lt rgb "#40FF00"
```