# Make gnuplot remove unnecessary text from the graph

Tags: gnuplot

This is my script

```
set title "Frequency graph"
set xlabel "Words"
set ylabel "Frequency"

set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
plot "gnuplot.data" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes


pause -1 "Hit any key to continue"
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551808/2411320) answer.

The result is this:
[image]
You see, I want that "gnuplot.data" using 1:3:xtic(2) and the red horizontal bar to disappear. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a line `set key off` before the `plot` command.

Comment: Thank you DragonHu, really laconic answer!

Comment: for more options of `set key`, type `help key` in the gnuplot command interface.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `notitle` option to the plot command, i.e. `plot "gnuplot.data" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes notilte`

Answer (score 0):

You can just

```
plot "gnuplot.data" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes title ""
```