# How to plot a smooth surface in GNUplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with three columns. All three have different values. To plot it in a smooth surface with a color gradient for third column what should I do?

The data file is look like follows:

```
1431.564087 -556.7048268 -14.09538931
1445.544205 -562.1413974   0
1445.544205 -562.1413974  -6.577848346
1452.06826  -564.6784636   6.577848346
1445.544205 -562.1413974  -6.577848346
1452.06826  -564.6784636   9.396926208
1442.748182 -561.0540833  -1.879385242
1444.612197 -561.7789593  11.27631145
1433.428103 -557.4297029  -4.698463104
1438.088142 -559.2418931   4.698463104
1433.428103 -557.4297029   0
1433.428103 -557.4297029   0.939692621
1432.496095 -557.0672648  -0.939692621
1433.428103 -557.4297029   0
1433.428103 -557.4297029  -2.819077862
1436.224127 -558.517017   -1.879385242
1438.088142 -559.2418931   0
1438.088142 -559.2418931   0
1438.088142 -559.2418931   0
1438.088142 -559.2418931   6.577848346
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you plot bar charts in gnuplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327576/how-do-you-plot-bar-charts-in-gnuplot)

Comment: There are lots of questions already on using gnuplot and bar charts or histograms. Please check that one of them doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you dont have gridded data, you must first interpolate them with gnuplot's dgrid3d or with an other tool. Suppose your data is in data.txt:

```
set dgrid3d 50,50,1
set pm3d map
splot 'data.txt'
```