# Is there any charting library in elixir?

Tags: graph, erlang, elixir

I want to plot a bar graph in elixir and save it as an image.

Is there any good charting library for doing this ?

I tried searching on [elixir.libhunt.com](https://elixir.libhunt.com/) and [github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir](https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir), but didn't find a single package for my need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [edg_chart](https://github.com/psyeugenic/eplot/blob/master/src/egd_chart.erl) from Erlang for bar chart.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Asking to find a library is considered off-topic. If you had any questions about a specific library, that would be on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any such control for Elixir--nothing native anyway.  Graphics is not exactly in Elixir's wheelhouse.  However, I think you could probably build something yourself with [wxErlang](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/wx/).  You can see what sorts of things you can do with wxErlang in Elixir by typing `:wx.demo()` from within iex. I don't know of a graph primitive in wxErlang but it may be that I simply haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 6):

Yes - you can interface to [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) with [gnuplot-elixir](https://github.com/devstopfix/gnuplot-elixir)

As as example, to generate the [bar graph in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551808/3366) - the code would be:

```
import Gnuplot

chart = [
      [:set, :term, :png, :size, '512,512'],
      [:set, :output, Path.join("/tmp", "barchart.PNG")],
      [:set, :boxwidth, 0.5],
      ~w(set style fill solid)a,
      [:plot, "-", :using, '1:3:xtic(2)', :with, :boxes]
    ]

dataset = [[0, "label", 100], [1, "label2", 450], [2, "bar label", 75]]

plot(chart, [dataset])
```

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this question, you can now use the `vega_lite` package and LiveBook to easily plot with Elixir.

https://livebook.dev/

https://github.com/livebook-dev/vega_lite