# plotting bar chart in gnuplot directly without input file

Tags: linux, gnuplot, bar-chart

I am following [plot bar graphs in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327576/how-do-you-plot-bar-charts-in-gnuplot) but I am not able to plot my data. Here is how it should look like

[image: Result Graph]

Here is my code

```
!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist

  
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid

plot  (1,"label1",664;2,"label2",331) using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
```

Error

```
plot  (1,"label1",664;2,"label2",331) using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
                     ^
"./test.sh", line 10: ')' expected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a data block for saving online data

```
$data <<EOD
1 "label" 664
2 "label2" 331
EOD

set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid

plot  $data using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
```

Comment: How to set xrange and yrange as shown in the example plot?