# How can I put names on the chart with gnuplot?

Tags: linux, shell, charts, gnuplot

I have a txt file with names and quantities, for example:

```
1 70 cats
2 64 dogs
3 54 birds
4 30 turtles
```

how can I, only with gnuplot, generate a chart in which the names below and their respective quantities appear on the right ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked the manual and the gnuplot homepage and basic tutorials? Are you talking of a vertical bar graph or a horizontal bar graph? Please clarify and/or add a sketch to illustrate.

Comment: Yes, I read it but I couldn’t find it, it’s a box Graph bar, with the names written horizontally

Comment: is someone like that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327576/how-do-you-plot-bar-charts-in-gnuplot 

but I tried the way this one there and it didn’t work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Which of the many different answers did you try? Please show some code, result (error message or output graph) and a description of what is different to your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If the graph you want to create is just a point chart, you can do it by combining the `with points` and `with labels` plots. Here is a sample code.

```
$TestData <<EOD
1 70 cats
2 64 dogs
3 54 birds
4 30 turtles
5 25 "other animals"
EOD

set xrange [0:6]
set yrange [0:100]
set key noautotitle

plot $TestData using 1:2 with points ps 2 pt 7, \
     ""        using 1:2:(strcol(3)) with labels offset 0,-1 center, \
     ""        using 1:2:(strcol(2)) with labels offset 2,0 left
```

[image: Image generated by sample code]